# Word for a person who is very much interested in having her photographs clicked?

Tags: single-word-requests

No, I am not talking about selfies.
This person misses no opportunity to be in each and every photo shoot at a gathering.

Last time, I remember, at a function we had a choice of getting her for a particular task or her sister in law. She hurried to get the task done (pretending she was very much interested in doing that). She in fact knew that the photographs would be taken and that was the actual reason that was hurrying.

Word for a person who is very much interested in having his photographs clicked?

Comment: This one sounds  more like an obsession than merely an ardor.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clicked'? Do you mean having their photo taken or do you mean that their avatar or whatever is clicked on a website.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK first option. This person is obsessed about it.

Comment: A person attracted to photo opportunities to an obsessive degree ought to be called a _flash moth_.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by 'clicked' someone who likes getting into random photos, then I suggest

photo-bomber